# Cron PHP simplexml error

Tags: php, cron

I have written something that will import an external XML file.
Everything works (fetching, reading, processing and saving) when executed from the browser.

However, it's not intended to be run manually every hour from the browser, so I need to set a cronjob for this:

[image]

I don't get anything from the file.
When I put in:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$xml = simplexml_load_file(<external-URL>); 

if (!$xml) {
  $errors = libxml_get_errors();

  foreach ($errors as $error) {
    print_r( $error );
  }
  libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

This is the output from CRON:

```
LibXMLError Object
(
    [level] => 1
    [code] => 1549
    [column] => 0
    [message] => failed to load external entity ""

    [file] =>
    [line] => 0
)
```

I've asked our hosting partner and they said 'allow_url_fopen' is turned on on every instance where it could matter.

I've searched all over the internet and I'm at a loss now.

I'm not that familiar with CRON, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Nahbyr

Comment: this looks like you trying to load an empty string. Make sure your `<external-URL>` is actually containing an actual url or filename to load.

Comment: are you using CPanel (godaddy?)

Comment: It looks that way, but I've checked and triple checked. The XML isn't empty. As I said, manually the same script works, only CRON has a problem fetching the XML.

Comment: Yes, I am using CPanel.

Comment: @Nahbyr when you set up the cronjob, two things are usually done. 1) you set the intervals in which you wish the script to be executed, and 2), you set the path for the script. Can you paste in your question what you pasted in the path,  as well as what you set up in the time intervals? It might be easier to take a screenshot.

Comment: @Webeng I've added a screenshot. It's set to every 5 minutes right now for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this path you have:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/******/public_html/******/test2.php
```

Try using this path:

```
php /home/******/public_html/******/test2.php
```

Let me know if it works now!

Comment: Looks like that did it! Thanks!

Comment: @Nahbyr no problem dude, I've been exactly when you are (or were) when I started tweeking with cron jobs :)

Comment: @Nahbyr oh and I edited out the info you blurred up in the pic

Comment: Thanks. Not that it really matters, but you never know.